# I can't get this simple python code to work?

Tags: python

**Hi I am new to python, please can you point me in the right direction. I am getting an error on line 23. I am getting the following erro
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**

```
# the lower and upper
import random
import math
lower = 1
upper = 100
x = random.randint(lower, upper)
print("\n\tYou've only ", round(math.log(upper-lower + 1, 2))," chances to guess the integer!\n")

 # Initializing the number of guesses.
count = 0

# for calculation of minimum number of
# guesses depends upon range
while count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
 count += 1

 # taking guessing number as input
 guess = int(input("Guess a number:- ")) 
 # Condition testing
 if guess == 'number':
  print('Congratulations! You guessed it.')
 elif guess < 'number':
  print("you guessed too small!")
else:
 print("you guessed too big!")

# If Guessing is more than required guesses, 
# shows this output.
if count >= math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
 print("\nThe number is %d"%x)
 print("\tBetter Luck Next time!")
```

Comment: You converted the user input `guess` to an `int`, so why are you trying to compare it to a string?

Comment: I read your code in a glance, and I guess you want to compare `guess` with `x` but not the string `"number"`.

Comment: 'number' should be a int and not a String.  number=10      guess < number

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare `guess`, which is a number to `'number'`, which is text. Python tells you that checking if a number is smaller than the text `'number'` doesn't make any sense.

What are you trying to accomplish here?

EDIT: My guess would be that you are trying to check if the user guessed `x`. In that case you would have to replace `'number'` with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with freundTech: you have to compare guess with x.
Then, I suggest you to insert a boolean variable, so you can exit from the while loop, when the user guessed the correct number.
Finally, I modify the while condition, because otherwise the user have one more chance:

```
while (count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2) - 1 and guessed == False):
```

Here's the code

```
 # Initializing the number of guesses.
count = 0
guessed = False # <-- Boolean variable

# for calculation of minimum number of
# guesses depends upon range


while (count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2) - 1 and guessed == False): # <-- Change while condition
 count += 1

 # taking guessing number as input
 guess = int(input("Guess a number:- ")) 
 # Condition testing
 if guess == x:
  print('Congratulations! You guessed it.')
  guessed = True # <--- The user chooses the correct number: now he will exit from the loop
 elif guess < x:
  print("you guessed too small!")
 else:
  print("you guessed too big!")

# If Guessing is more than required guesses, 
# shows this output.
if count >= math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2) - 1:
 print("\nThe number is %d"%x)
 print("\tBetter Luck Next time!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `number` to `x` to compare with `int` not a `str`:

**Code Syntax**

```
if guess == x:
  print('Congratulations! You guessed it.')
elif guess < x:
  print("you guessed too small!")
else:
 print("you guessed too big!")
```